# Footer on the bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer, responsive

I'm stuck with a footer.

I have this code - https://jsfiddle.net/annaolsh/pLzv5sg5/13/

```
#footer {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}
```

On a small screen the navbar is displayed on the top and footer is on the bottom - that's correct.

But on big screens when navbar is displayed vertically on the left side, footer disappears. Can't figure out how to display the footer. It doesn't need to be sticky: user needs to scroll down and see it (same as on small screens). Footer's width should be 100% of screen size.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In given code snippet positioning is off. There is some work to be done with position of each element on your page. The only node having position set is left menu and it's fixed.

The easiest fix would be to play with following css:

```
#footer {
   position: relative;
   clear:both;
   padding: 1rem;
   background-color: orange;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Remove left, bottom and right. Just add position relative and clear:both.

DEMO: 
https://jsfiddle.net/pLzv5sg5/14/

Comment: You said there is to work to be done with position of each element. But you fixed the problem just playing with one element. Is it a bad solution?

Comment: You may have some problems when the solution grows. For now it's fine! :)
For future I recommend to don't leave the position set to default as sometimes, when child nodes inherit position from parent nodes, things go really bad :D

Answer (score 0):

Add footer code inside content wrapper i.e **container-fluid**
use following CSS code for footer:

```
#footer {
 padding: 1rem;
 background-color: orange;
 text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rppmvgeo/

Comment: But I need footer width takes 100% of screen width. In this case footer displays to the right from navbar. How can footer overlap navbar?